# Ract Native, scroll to specific place in screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I Have food app and in restaurant screen, I want when to click on pizza react-native scroll to pizza section, if user click on the burger the page scroll tp burger section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First:
You need to measure where is the exact point each section, like this.
[0,356,650,760] (onLayout)

Second:
You need to create a ref to the ScrollView

Third:
On Onpress, you need to call the ScrollView, scrollTo function.

For example:
You know, the user pressed the third element(Burger), so you call the scrollRef.current.scrollTo(points[3]).

Comment: I did it, thanks to organize my thinking,,,, just last question now i want when pizza section appear the button of pizza in apove section to be colored

Comment: I did a similar a couple weeks ago, so i will make a snack today with explanation.